Django PyCryptodome AES decryption - ValueError: Padding is incorrect
I am trying to encrypt incoming files and than decrypt them later. I was following the documentation for how to use AES with CBC mode for decryption and encryption.
My view for uploading and encrypting file:
@router.post("/upload_files")
def upload_files(request, file: UploadedFile = File(...)):
    save_file = operations.aes_encryption(user_id=request.auth.id,file=request.FILES.get('file'))

def aes_encryption(self,user_id,file):
        user = UserQueries.get_user(id=user_id)
        key: bytes = bytes(user.key, "utf-8")
        path: str = user.path

        save_file = self._encrypt_file(file,key,path,user)

        return save_file
    
    def _encrypt_file(self,file,key,path,user):
        file_content = file.read()

        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
        ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(file_content, AES.block_size))

        iv = b64encode(cipher.iv).decode('utf-8')
        ct = b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')

        with open(str(settings.BASE_STORAGE_DIR)+"/"+path+file.name,"wb") as f:
            f.write(ct.encode('utf-8'))

        return save_metadata

This code works like it should it encrypts the file and stores it in directory. My key and iv is stored in database as string.
This is my decryption function where I am having trouble:
def aes_decryption(self,request, file_id):
        user = UserQueries.get_user(id=request.auth.id)
        file = FileQueries.get_file_data(id=file_id)

        iv = b64decode(file.iv)
        key = b64decode(user.key)

        with open(str(settings.BASE_STORAGE_DIR)+"/"+file.path,"rb") as f:
            cipher = f.read()
        
        decrypt_file = self._decrypt_file(iv,key,cipher_text=cipher)
        
    def _decrypt_file(self,iv,key,cipher_text):

        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(cipher_text), AES.block_size)

When calling the decryption I am getting this error:
Padding is incorrect.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cloud-hub-backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 107, in run
    result = self.view_func(request, **values)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Documents/cloud_project/backend/cloud_hub_backend/cloud_hub_backend/apps/file_storage/views.py", line 67, in download_files
    file, content_type, file_name = operations.aes_decryption(request,file_id)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Documents/cloud_project/backend/cloud_hub_backend/cloud_hub_backend/apps/file_storage/operations.py", line 59, in aes_decryption
    decrypt_file = self._decrypt_file(iv,key,cipher_text=cipher)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Documents/cloud_project/backend/cloud_hub_backend/cloud_hub_backend/apps/file_storage/operations.py", line 66, in _decrypt_file
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(cipher_text), AES.block_size)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cloud-hub-backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Padding.py", line 92, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.

This is how my key and iv is stored in database:
key: B5A647A95DECADB7A3B715D7F6602344
iv: enW82aTDyK4ILhfLPLXRrA==
I was trying to resolve this issue with following questions but unsuccessfully:

I do it in the correct order
My keys match
Has no answer


Possibly an encoding issue: E.g. where is cipher_text Base64 decoded during encryption? Or, why does your key look hex encoded, but is Base64 decoded during decryption? Check the encodings. If you can't fix the issue, post non-productive test data: Use a file with a short plaintext (e.g. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog). Regarding aes_encryption/_encrypt_file log and post user.key, iv and ct. Regarding aes_decryption/_decrypt_file log and post file.iv, user.key and cipher_text.
